# Algebraic Logic, Boolean Algebra, proofing an equation

Tags: logic

proof that:

`((a∧b) ∨ (not a ∧ b)) ∧ (( not c ∧ not d) ∨ (not(c ∨ d))` is equal to `b ∧ not c ∧ not d`.

My suggestion would be to use the Morgan's law in the beginning:

`((a∧b) ∨ (not a ∧ b)) ∧ (( not c ∧ not d) ∨ (not c ∧ not d))` is equal to `b ∧ not c ∧ not d`.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The expression has the form `x ∧ y` where

```
                         x = (a∧b) ∨ (not a ∧ b)
                           = (a ∨ not a) ∧ b                    ; distribution
                           = true ∧ b
                           = b

                         y = (not c ∧ not d) ∨ (not(c ∨ d))
                           = (not c ∧ not d) ∨ (not c ∧ not d)  ; De Morgan
                           = not c ∧ not d                       ; A ∨ A = A
```

Therefore

```
                     x ∧ y = b ∧ not c ∧ not d
```